# Sap HANA Studio change SAP GUI resolution

Tags: sap-gui, sap-bw, hana-studio

I can't change the SAP GUI resolution, can't find the option. I've changed the font size scaling factor to the minimum that is 80%, under Window->Preferences->SAP GUI Integration, but the result was pretty much the same:

[image]

The menu and icons are too big, and I do not have the complete picture of the transformation. How can I change resolution? Maybe in some .ini file?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, only change a percent button to 50% or the best to you. Doing this you can see all arrows from and to transformation.